# Oracle SYS views missing from DB instance

Tags: oracle, performance, restore, sys

Hi i have a question but not sure what the problem was and how it happened though.

The initial error when i logged in the DB dev machine was ORA-00942: table or view does not exists. Some of the system views that we tried to access gave a ORA-017775: looping chain of synonyms.

Then we noticed some of the ALL_* and DBA_* views and functions were missing, which were causing alot of the dependencies and system packages to throw errors.

We also noticed that the SYSTEM tablespace has reached 100% utilized space.

So my question is, is it possible when the SYSTEM tablespace runs out of space, it would randomly drop the SYS views and functions

We also checked the alert logs, seems like it happened during a non-working period. Or is there any logs that i could further check on what happened that caused SYS views and functions being dropped suddenly ?

[image]
Regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, the database will not drop its own views.

But I have seen this many times, for example when developers thought naming their own tables as 'T$...' and views as 'V$...' was a good idea, then they wanted to clean up their schema, but they messed up all the V$ synonyms and views.

I would just start the database in upgrade mode and run the below scripts to rebuild these objects:

```
@?/rdbms/admin/catalog.sql
@?/rdbms/admin/catproc.sql
@?/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
```

[Run Scripts to Build Data Dictionary Views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/create.htm#ADMIN11082)

Comment: Thanks , the solution worked to rebuild back most of the object